# passing the contour vector to moments() vs passing the image with the contour to moments()

Tags: c++, opencv, contour

I want to get the descriptor of each symbol contained inside binary image so i can train/predict with an SVM. I figured that i needed to find the contours of each symbol in the image and then extract each descriptor (one for each contour). Im getting the descriptors of the symbols using `huMoments` and for that i need the moments of the symbol.

The function `moments()` receives an image as a  `Mat` object or a vector of points. That means i can pass one the vectors of points returned by `contours()` as well as a binary image where i draw and fill that specific contour. So my question is:

Is there any difference between the moments i get using the vector returned by  `contours()` as a parameter and the moments i would get using the image with the contour drawn? Is one option better than the other in terms of precision?

## example:

Suppose that the vector of points i get from `contours()` is something like this (this is an example and are not real points calculated by the function):

[image]

If i draw the contour formed by that vector of points in a `Mat` and fill the inside part i get an image like this:

[image]

My question is if the second image's `moments()` brings more information at the time of SVM learning/predicting than the vector of points (the first image), Therefore improving the accuracy of the prediction?

Comment: With contours you'll get only boundary points, while moments are computed on all (also internals) points. So it depends on your binary image, but in general they are not the same. You can use `findNonZero` to get all non-black pixels into a vector. A sample image a and a code snippet will be helpful for more precise answers.

Comment: @Miki edited the question with an example

Comment: Result will be different, whether better or worse for your svm it's up to you.